# Qt: Paint function of custom LineEditDelegate

Tags: c++, qt, delegates, paint, qlineedit

I have implemented ComboBoxDelegate. It is derived from `QStyledItemDelegate`. Paint function is used to show the content of cell when it is not editing node.

```
void ComboBoxDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const {
    QStyleOptionComboBox comboBoxOption;
    comboBoxOption.rect = option.rect;
    comboBoxOption.state = QStyle::State_Active | QStyle::State_Enabled;
    comboBoxOption.frame = true;
    comboBoxOption.currentText = index.model()->data(index).toString();
    QApplication::style()->drawComplexControl(QStyle::CC_ComboBox, &comboBoxOption, painter);
    QApplication::style()->drawControl(QStyle::CE_ComboBoxLabel, &comboBoxOption, painter);
}
```

Now I am trying to implement LineEditDelegate. I don't know how to write its paint function. Is there `QStyleOptionComboBox` like class for QLineEdit? Can you please share your code if anyone have done it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9897594/qt-how-to-draw-a-dummy-line-edit-control/9908536#9908536).

It uses `QStyle::drawPrimitive` with `QStyle::PE_PanelLineEdit` element.